# PromptAndInput, cannot convert string into double

Tags: c#, module, implicit-conversion

I'm having issues compiling a program. Errors have pointed to that PromptAndInput("any of the text"); cannot implicitly convert string to double

```
    name = PromptAndInput( "Enter the name of the customer: ");
    state = PromptAndInput( "In which state (NY / NJ / FL) ? ");

    if (state != "NJ" & state != "nj" & state != "NY" & state != "ny" & state != "FL" & state != "fl") {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        while (state != "NJ" & state != "nj" & state != "NY" & state != "ny" & state != "FL" & state != "fl") {
            state = PromptAndInput("In which state (NY / NJ / FL) ? ");
        }
    }

    itemQuantity = PromptAndInput("How many items were purchased?: ");

    if (itemQuantity < 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        while (itemQuantity < 0) {
            itemQuantity = PromptAndInput("How many items were purchased?: ");
        }
    }

    itemPrice = PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: ");

    if (itemPrice < 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
        while (itemPrice < 0) {
            itemPrice = PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: ");
        }
    }

    computeTotal(itemQuantity, itemPrice, total, name);
    computeTax(state, total, itemQuantity, itemPrice);
```

---

i'm sure it is easy to spot, but since i'm working with modules i'm not sure how to work around the use of PromptAndInput

What can i do here?

---

AFTER FIRST FIX

itemQuantity = double.Parse(PromptAndInput("How many items were purchased?: "));

```
        if (itemQuantity < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            while (itemQuantity < 0)
            {
                itemQuantity = double.Parse(PromptAndInput("How many items were purchased?: "));
            }
        }

        itemPrice = int.Parse(PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: "));

        if (itemPrice < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            while (itemPrice < 0)
            {
                itemPrice = int.Parse(PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: "));



                computeTotal(itemQuantity, itemPrice, total, name);
                computeTax(state, total, itemQuantity, itemPrice);

            }
        }
    }

//function for read and write
public static string PromptAndInput(string prompt)
{
    string userInput = null;
    Console.Write(prompt);
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    return userInput;
}

//function for total sales
public static object computeTotal(double itemQuantity, int itemPrice, double total, string name)
{

    total = itemQuantity * itemPrice;
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("The total sales for " + name + " are: " + total);

    return total;
}
```

The code is suppose to continue after

```
itemPrice = int.Parse(PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: "));
```

not sure whats causing the end

Comment: What does `PromptAndInput` do? Where is that code? Is that where the errors are thrown?

Comment: Since they are strings you probably need to check the input and then try to get the `double` from the strings if it has a certain format that can be converted. If it can't they prompt the user again to put the input in a certain format that can be converted.

Comment: Look at the example found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: alright, i fixed it, the problem was i needed to add promptandinput into the the parenthesis and close. the outside is labelled  double.parse for the first set and int.parse for the second

Comment: However, although no errors are shown, when running the program. After user input "what was the unit price of the item", it halts the run.

Answer (score 0):

The return for `PromptAndInput` is `String`

```
public static string PromptAndInput(string prompt)
```

So in the code where you call this, you need to parse the returned text:

```
itemQuantity = Int32.Parse(PromptAndInput("How many items were purchased?: "));

itemPrice = Double.Parse(PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: "));
```

Comment: True. though now after having changed it to that line, now the program ends abruptly after : itemPrice = Double.Parse(PromptAndInput("What was the unit price of the items?: ")); which is not suppose to happen